# Calling Fortran functions from R

Tags: r, fortran

It is straight forward to call a Fortran **subroutine** from R using `.Fortran` and there are examples available online. However, I haven't found any direct way to call a Fortran **function** from R.

Currently, I use an interface for that, which gets the Fortran function and uses it in a subroutine, but it is very time consuming to do so for all external functions.

Is there an elegant way to call Fortran **functions** directly from R?

Comment: The documentation is quite clear: "Note that the compiled code should not return anything except through its arguments: C functions should be of type void and Fortran subprograms should be subroutines."

Comment: That is right. I am just wondering, that there is no way to call fortran functions directly from R.

Comment: You mean, having read the documentation saying explicitly, "X is impossible", your question is "is X possible?"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, to be fair to Moji, the documentation says "X is impossible using Y", so the answer to "is X possible?" is not an immediate consequence if there are ways other than "Y".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Having read my question, I never said it should be using `.Fortran` as @francescalus mentioned. So you can save yourself the mathemathical proof.

Answer (score 6):

With `.Fortran` (and `.C`) it is not possible to use Fortran functions, as noted in [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eC-and-_002eFortran):

> Note that the compiled code should not return anything except through its arguments: C functions should be of type void and Fortran subprograms should be subroutines.

Using `.Call` (and `.External`) it is possible to call Fortran functions, but it's fair to say that doing this makes writing a subroutine wrapper for the Fortran function look trivial: minimally you'll be writing a C wrapper to be invoked in the middle (making this another "indirect" Fortran function call - directly calling a Fortran function will require even more effort).